# Add id attribute to body tag in drupal

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm trying to add an id to the `<body>` tag in my drupal theme. Currently I am doing it in the following manner:

PHP

```
function myTheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
    $variables['bodyId'] = $variables['is_front'] ? 'id="page-AnaSayfa"' : 'id="page"';
}
```

HTML:

```
<body class="<?php print $classes;?>" <?php print $attributes;?> <?php print $bodyId;?>>
```

I am wondering is there a way to do it using the `$attributes` variable? So far what I have tried with it didn't work which led me to use the `$bodyId` I have now.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.

Change it from :

```
function myTheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
    $variables['bodyId'] = $variables['is_front'] ? 'id="page-AnaSayfa"' : 'id="page"';
}
```

To:

```
function sat7turk_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
    $variables['attributes_array']['id'] = $variables['is_front'] ? 'page-AnaSayfa' : 'page';
}
```